# Can Pre-Defined Database be Updated by User? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio, so please bear with me
I want to make an app that have list of quotes and there's a favorite button besides each quote

so i make pre defined database using SQLite Browser, after i create the db
i open Android studio and right click and paste at the assets folder.

So my questions is

1) How can i update my database when user click on the favorite button on some quotes ? So that the app knows which one are the user favorites and listed it on another activity

2) I want to update my list of quotes using SQlite Browser and just replace the old database file from assets folder with the new one. But when i try to test it on bluestacks, it only shows the previous database files.

3) If SQLite cannot be updated while using pre-defined database, is there anything else that i can use beside SQLite?

Here's my Codes

**DatabaseOpenHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mqn.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "quote";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_QUOTES = "quotesText";
public static final String COLUMN_AUTHOR= "author";
public static final String COLUMN_FAV = "fav";

private SQLiteDatabase database;

private final Context context;

// database path
private static String DATABASE_PATH;

/** constructor */
public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = ctx;
    DATABASE_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath()
            + "/databases/";

}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void create() throws IOException {
    boolean check = checkDataBase();

    SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;

    // Creates empty database default system path
    db_Read = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db_Read.close();
    try {
        if (!check) {
            copyDataBase();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 *
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

/** open the database */
public void open() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

/** close the database */
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null)
        database.close();
    super.close();
}

// insert a user into the database
public long insertUser(String quotesText, String author, String fav) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_QUOTES, quotesText );
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_AUTHOR, author);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_FAV, fav);
    return database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
}

// updates a user
public boolean updateUser(long rowId, String quotesText, String author,
                          String fav) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COLUMN_QUOTES, quotesText);
    args.put(COLUMN_AUTHOR, author);
    args.put(COLUMN_FAV, fav);
    return database.update(TABLE_NAME, args, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves a particular user
public Cursor getUser(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                    COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_QUOTES, COLUMN_AUTHOR, COLUMN_FAV },
            COLUMN_ID + " = " + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}

// delete a particular user
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) {
    return database.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

// retrieves all users
public Cursor getAllUsers() {
    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
                    COLUMN_QUOTES, COLUMN_AUTHOR, COLUMN_FAV }, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**QuotesActivity.java**

```
public class QuotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView title;
Typeface myFont;
ListView quotesList;
ListView favLV;
DatabaseOpenHelper myDbHelper;
DatabaseAccess databaseAccess;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes);

    myDbHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);

    try {
        // check if database exists in app path, if not copy it from assets
        myDbHelper.create();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
        // open the database
        myDbHelper.open();
        myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    populateListView();



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_button);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleQuote);
    myFont =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Montserrat-Bold.otf");
    title.setTypeface(myFont);
    title.setTextSize(20);
    title.setTextColor(Color.rgb(240, 239, 223));

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

private void populateListView() {
    Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.getAllUsers();
    String[] from = new String[] {myDbHelper.COLUMN_QUOTES, myDbHelper.COLUMN_AUTHOR};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.quoteLV, R.id.authorLV};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.quotes_listview, cursor, from, to,0);
    quotesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.quotesList);
    quotesList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
}
```

**Content_quotes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="hendrasetiawan.mqn.QuotesActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_quotes">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/quotesList"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/favList"
            android:layout_weight="6" />


    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**quotes_listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/quoteLV"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/authorLV"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android does not provide any methods or APIs for using the external SQLite databases (which are stored in the Asset folder). However, I came across a library one day that could solve your problem. Here is the link:

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Download this library from the webpage and add it to your project in the Android Studio. I, personally have not used this library. However, this library contains some samples or demo code which can be useful and there will definitely be someone on StackOverflow who would have used it. They might be able to help you.

Hope this library solves your problem and Good Luck.